# Countdown in blade with js

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, countdown

I have this problem in laravel blade. I have a project where the opportunity is given to sponsor apartments for greater visibility. Depending on the plan chosen, the sponsorship lasts 24 72 or 144 hours. Now I would like to make a countdown that shows how much time is left at the end of the sponsorship . This is my code in blade :

```
@foreach (DB::table("apartment_sponsorship")->where("apartment_id" ,"=" , $apartment->id) -> get() as $end_time_sponsor)
                  <p class="demo"></p>
                    <script>
                    var countDownDate = new Date("{{$end_time_sponsor -> end_time }}").getTime();
                    console.log(countDownDate)

                      // Update the count down every 1 second
                      var x = setInterval(function() {

                        // Get today's date and time
                        var now = new Date().getTime();



                        // Find the distance between now and the count down date
                        var distance = countDownDate - now;

                        // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
                        var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
                        var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
                        var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
                        var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

                        // Output the result in an element with id="demo"
                        $(".demo").text(days + "d " + hours + "h "
                        + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");



                      }, 1000);

                  </script> 
                      //test{{date('m-d-Y H:m:s', strtotime($end_time_sponsor -> end_time)) }} //

                  @endforeach
```

now the log confirms that endtime is actually of 2 different dates, however on the page the countdown is the same for all apartments. What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your foreach loop from

```
`@foreach (DB::table("apartment_sponsorship")->where("apartment_id" ,"=" ,
 $apartment->id) -> get() as $end_time_sponsor)`
```

to

```
$query = DB::table("apartment_sponsorship")->where("apartment_id" ,"=" , $apartment->id)->get()
@foreach ($query as $end_time_sponsor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you please try like this -

```
@php
    $end_time_sponsors = DB::table("apartment_sponsorship")
                          ->where("apartment_id" ,"=" , $apartment->id)
                          ->get()
@endphp
```

Then,

```
@foreach($end_time_sponsors as $end_time_sponsor)
    <p data-countdown="{{ date('Y/m/d', strtotime($end_time_sponsor->end_time)) }}">
        {{ date('Y/m/d', strtotime($end_time_sponsor->end_time)) }}
    </p>
@endforeach
```

In your script tag:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery.countdown.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    $('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
       var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
       $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
         $this.html(event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S'));
       });
    });
</script>
```

To download [jQueryCountdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)